# change the setting of datatable after it initialized

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a datatable with some settings,

```
 $(tblCategory).dataTable({
            "bPaging": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers", //
            "bPaginate": false, // shows both next prvious and show 10,20,30 entries
            "sdom": 't',
            "bprocessing": false, //
            "sAjaxSource": "PM_MasterHelper.ashx?m=pmcfl&UserCode="+UserCode,
            "bFilter": false, // search btn avail
                "bDestroy": true
}
```

Now i would like to alter or add the settings like "bInfo":true, "bPaginate":true, when i click html input button.

Please help me to achieve this.

Try 1:
I tried the following way but it doesn't affect the datatable.

```
 oTable = $("tblCategory").dataTable();
 var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
 oSettings.bInfo= true;
oSettings.bPaginate = true;
```

Comment: You need to [destroy](https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy%28%29) the datatable and reinitialise it with your new settings.

Answer (score 9):

You Should reinitialize the datatable:

```js
//Default Options Object
var tableOptions = {
        'bPaginate': true,
        'searching' : true
    };
//The table has already been initialized
var table = $("#ExampleTable");
  tableOptions.bPaginate = true;
  table.DataTable().destroy()
  table.DataTable(tableOptions);
```

Answer (score 5):

According to the [documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3):

> Simply put, DataTables does not allow initialisation options to be altered at any time other than at initialisation time. Any manipulation of the table after initialisation must be done through the API

The solution is to destroy the table:

```
table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    paging: false
} );

table.destroy();

table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    searching: false
} );
```

You can also do:

```
table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    destroy: true,
    searching: false
});
```

This has some performance consequences and it will also reset paging.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a `DataTable().destroy()` before apply the new options, example:

```
oTable = $("tblCategory").DataTable();
var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
oSettings.bInfo= true;
oSettings.bPaginate = true;
oTable.destroy();
$("tblCategory").DataTable(oSettings);
```

Also u need to use DataTable() with capital D.

Answer (score -2):

Store datatable in variable 
var tableCategory = $j(tblCategory).dataTable(...
and then change properties on settings object

Comment: yes i did like that too i get an error as "Cannot Reinitialize a datatable"

Comment: https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/16373/enable-disable-features-after-initializing-the-table

Comment: "The information in this object is generally considered to be private and should not be used directly. It absolutely should not have settings written to unless you know the DataTables internals well enough to know the effect of what writing to a property will have." https://datatables.net/reference/api/settings()  so only "The short answer is that you cannot alter initialisation options after the table has been initialised, unless there is an API available for it. You need to reinitialise the table."

Comment: I guess that You will have to use their api to change things like order http://datatables.net/reference/api/order()  http://datatables.net/reference/api/column().order() or page length http://datatables.net/reference/api/page.len()